# Updating a column in SQL table where items are identified in another table that is linked

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, lookup

I have two tables in MSSQL.

Table1

[image]

Table2

[image]

I want to update the Status column in Table 1 to "YES" if the same Ticket ID, House and Part Number exists in Table 2. After updating, Table 1 should be like,

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple `EXISTS()` will do the job

```
UPDATE t1
SET    Status = 'Yes'
FROM   Table1 t1         
WHERE  EXISTS
       (
             SELECT *
             FROM   Table2 t2
             WHERE  t1.TicketID   = t2.TicketID
             AND    t1.House      = t2.House
             AND    t1.PartNumber = t2.PartNumber
       )
```

or an `INNER JOIN` will gives you the query that you want